# What is the best way to show the convexity of a function of multiple variables?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have a function of multiple variables, defined as a vector $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n) $ as follows:
$f(x) = \frac{1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{\alpha-(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)}$ with $(\alpha-(1-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)) \geq 0$.

How to show the convexity of this function by showing that the n-dimensional Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite? The elements of the Hessian matrix are given as follows:
$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2} = \frac{2\alpha}{(\alpha-(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i))^3}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i} = \frac{2\alpha}{(\alpha-(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i))^3}$.

Comment: I think your partial derivatives are incorrect

Comment: Thanks. Rectified the issue in original post, but still, that doesn't solve the actual question I asked. Can anyone please help?

Comment: 1. It's definitely not convex over all possible values of $x$.
2. Have you examined the function $g(z)=z/(\alpha-z)$? How might that help you?

Comment: I agree Michael that this function is convex only for $(\alpha-(1-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)) \geq 0$. That is sufficient for me as I intend to operate only on that segment.